# Partial derivative = 0 implies function is invariant of the variable

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $G$ be a path connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$ such that for $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb R$ at any point $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$. Does $f(x,y)$ is invariant of $y$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, even if you assume $f$ is differentiable.  Consider $G = \mathbb R^2 \backslash \{(x,0): x \le 0\}$ (i.e. the complement of the nonpositive $x$ axis).  Take 
$$f(x,y) = \cases{0 & for $x \ge 0$\cr 
                  -x^2 & for $x < 0$ with $y < 0$\cr
                   x^2 & for $x < 0$ with $y > 0$\cr} $$

Comment: @Robert Israel: The question looks similar to Spivak's Calculus on Manifold question 2.22 at page $29$. Over there, if a function has zero derivative at second component, then the function is independent of it.

Comment: I don't have Spivak at hand, but I would expect him to get the statement right.